# When I try to crop single character pdf using "pdfcrop" cropped pdf is not valid

Tags: pdf, pdfcrop

I try to crop the PDF file using the command `pdfcrop --hires  1525503522236.pdf 1525503522236_cropped.pdf` I get the cropped PDF, but the cropped PDF file is not valid when opened in InDesign or Acrobat. This problem only occurs when the PDF file has only a single character (`i`):
[image]

Comment: the above figure is pdf before crop

Comment: i get the following error when open the cropped pdf in acrobat  **The dimensions of this page are out of range. Page content might be truncated. **

Comment: @egreg PDF/PostScript units are points with 72 points = 1 in. Thus, 3 units = 3 bp = 3.01125 pt (TeX points).

Comment: @egreg `0.04in` is annotated with "approximately" in the reference. The exact value is 0.0416666... in.

Answer (score 2):

The reason can be a too small media size, see the comments to the question.
The [PDF reference](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf) says in "Appendix C.2 Architectural Limits":

> The minimum page size should be 3 by 3 units in default user space;
>   the maximum should be 14,400 by 14,400 units. In versions of PDF
>   earlier than 1.6, the size of the default user space unit was fixed at
>   1/72  inch, yielding a minimum of approximately 0.04 by 0.04 inch and
>   a maximum of 200 by 200 inches. Beginning with PDF 1.6, the size of
>   the unit may be set on a page-by-page basis; the default remains at
>   1/72 inch.

I have some doubts that unit changes of PDF 1.6+ are supported by all the PDF viewers. Therefore, I suggest a different workaround, the procedure:

1. The image can be scaled:

   a) TeX level with `\mag`, for example:

   ```
   \mag=10000 % permille
   \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
   \begin{document}
     \textit{i}
   \end{document}
   ```

   b) Create a TeX document that includes the scaled image:

   ```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \begin{document}
     \includegraphics[scale=10]{uncropped.pdf}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Then, the image can be cropped:

   ```
   pdfcrop --hires --margin .1 scaled-uncropped.pdf cropped.pdf
   ```

   The bounding box depends on the resolution (curves, sharp corners). Therefore, I have added a safety margin to avoid that some pixels are cropped. Adapt to your needs.
3. Finally, the cropped image can be included with the reverse scale factor:

   ```
   \includegraphics[scale=.1]{cropped.pdf}
   ```

Comment: \mag=10000 give big font size pdf. Actual font size pdf not generated. I used 9.5pt as font size and 11.5pt is a leadding